# Какой глагол считать переходным

Tags: грамматика

Какой глагол считать переходным: тот, который в предложении сочетается с существительным в винительном падеже, или тот, который может сочетаться с существительным в винительном падеже, независимо, с каким существительным он сочетается в конкретном предложении? Например: *Я люблю бабушку за ее простоту и юмор* (люблю кого? вин. п. — переходный глагол), а в предложении: *Я люблю с бабушкой ходить в лес* (люблю с кем? с бабушкой — тв. п.) как считать: переходный этот глагол или непереходный? Или в первом предложении переходный, а во втором — непереходный. Как объяснить ребенку-шестикласснику? Или *учить в школе, учить детей.*

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я, возможно, попробую сформулировать ответ чуть позже.  Не могли бы вы процитировать, как это объясняет шестиклассникам учебник по русскому языку?

Comment: Попытку ответа отменяю по причине отсутствия обратной связи :) Самая трудная часть вопроса - про ребёнка-шестиклассника. Не зная, что написано в его учебнике, отвечать не хочется.

Comment: _Верьясова: Я люблю с бабушкой ходить в лес (**люблю с кем? с бабушкой** -Тв. падеж)_ === Нет, в этом предложении такого словосочетания нет. Есть такие: _люблю_ (что?) _ходить; ходить_ (с кем?) _с бабушкой_.

Comment: *Или в первом предложении переходный, а во втором — непереходный.* - до меня, кажется, дошла причина затруднений. Один и тот же глагол может быть переходным и непереходным в разных значениях. Но в данном случае у "любить" одно и то же значение. Только во втором примере в качестве переходного объекта выступает не существительное  в Вин.п.. а инфинитив "ходить". Он все равно отвечает на вопрос "люблю - что?"  Сама по себе возможность управления инфинитивом не свидетельствует о переходности глагола, но и не препятствует ей. Первый пример полностью покрывает все требования к признанию переходным.

Answer (score 2):

> тот, который может сочетаться с сущ. в винительном падеже

Это ближе к истине.

На самом деле вопрос вполне бестолково задан.

> который в предложении сочетается с существительным в Вин. падеже, или
>   тот, который может сочетаться с сущ. в винительном падеже,

Вы сами-то понимаете разницу? 
Я могу истолковать только так, что в первом случае пропущено слово "всегда". То есть глагол всегда, в любом предложении *требует винительного падежа - и только им управляет*. Но таких глаголов, наверное, и нет.

К сожалению, существующие модели грамматик не дают формального ответа на вопрос "А что есть переходный глагол?". Если же посмотреть в корень, то исходить надо из того, зачем вообще введена эта категория переходности глагола в русский язык. Единственное тому объяснение то, что ***такие глаголы образуют страдательные причастия*** (или отглагольные прилагательные, вопрос об их дифференциации здесь лучше вынести за скобки). Самое бы правильное именно это и взять за определение переходных глаголов. Но по формальным причинам авторы описаний грамматики от такого, казалось бы - простого, подхода вынуждены отказываться, поскольку это ведет к зацикливанию определений.

Тем не менее, выход есть, он всем хорошо известен. ***Такие глаголы, за единичными исключениями, позволяют иметь при себе так называемое "прямое дополнение"*** (в винительном без предлога), и это дополнение - опять-таки за редчайшими исключениями - и становится определяемым словом при страдательном причастии (или отглагольном прилагательном): любить бабушку - любимая бабушка, ранить бойца - ране(н)ный боец, грузить повозку - груженая повозка. Это и принимается за определение переходности большинством авторов.

Единственная частая сложность возникает с бесприставочными глаголами несовершенного вида, которые нормативных страдательных причастий иногда не имеют (строить дом - ?строемый дом), но это как правило  определяется не грамматической невозможностью такого образования, а лексической невостребованностью. Переходность в таком случае обычно определяется или через видовую пару (построенный дом), или через возвратное действительное причастие (строящийся дом) - любой из этих приемов подтверждает полноценную переходность глагола "строить".

Единичные оговорки, о которых я говорил выше, в основном сводятся к двум типам.
Во-первых, это глаголы, в которых в функциональной роли прямого дополнения выступает имя не в винительном, а в родительном падеже (ждать автобус - ждать автобуса). По всей логике глагол ждать - переходной, хотя образование от него страдательного причастия затруднительно. В формальных грамматиках этот вопрос оговоривается отдельно.

И, во-вторых, это глаголы, которые в силу разных причин сформировали особый тип управления переходным объектом ("управлять" - не "кого?/что?", а "кем?/чем?"). При этом существует причастие "управляемый" (как уже сказал, вопрос о том, причастие ли это, или отглагольное прилагательное выносим за скобки). Вот в отношении таких глаголов нет ни единства взглядов, ни хотя бы какой-то ясности в представлениях, считать ли их переходными.

Вот примерно круг вопросов, связанных с понятием переходности в русском языке. Из них можно сформировать ту или иную формулировку определения, что такое переходность. Это и будет ответом по сути на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

> Какой глагол считать переходным?.. Как объяснить ребенку-шестикласснику?

**Из учебника для 6-го класса (Русский язык. 6 класс / М.Т. Баранов и др.; 2011)**:

> Глаголы, которые **сочетаются** или **могут сочетаться** с
>   существительным, числительным или местоимением в винительном падеже
>   без предлога, называются **переходными**. Остальные глаголы являются
>   **непереходными**.

Как я понимаю эту формулировку из учебника? Примерно так: если в разбираемом предложении глагол имеет прямое дополнение, то этот глагол однозначно переходный; если же прямое дополнение при глаголе отсутствует, то это отнюдь не говорит о том, что рассматриваемый глагол однозначно непереходный. Требуется проверка возможности сочетаемости  этого глагола с дополнением в винительном падеже без предлога. И если такая сочетаемость возможна — глагол переходный.

**Из книги [Голанов И.Г. Морфология современного русского языка. М., 2007]**:

> Переходные глаголы могут иногда употребляться без прямого дополнения,
>   в более обобщённом значении, не становясь, однако, от этого
>   непереходными (как признавали некоторые учёные недавних лет): *Он
>   читает польскую книгу; Он читает по-польски; Он хорошо читает* — во
>   втором и третьем примерах, несмотря на отсутствие прямого дополнения,
>   глагол *читать*  сохраняет свою природу переходного глагола.

Comment: А как вы понимаете разницу между сочетаются и могут сшчетаться? Это ж не ЗАГС, где "сочетаться" могут все, а сочетаются - только отдельные граждане.

Comment: behemothus, я чуть дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Ясно. Другими словами, вы вслед за автороами сего опуса страхуетесь на тот случай, что кто-то вообразит, что переходность глагола зависит от конкретного контекста? Хуже того, от - конкретного предложения? Да... Сильно... Знаете, возникает ощущение, что автор просто не очень хорошо владеет русским языком. Ибо "Сочетаются или могут сочетаться" даже в такой постановке вопроса избыточно. "Могут сочетаться" вполне достаточно. да и просто "сочетаются" - понятно, ибо мало кто усомниться, что речь идет о потенцитальной сочетаемости... Ладно, это нет к вам, конечно, вопрос.

Comment: А что касается "Голанова И.Г.", то тут ключевое слово - *в более обобщенном  значении*. Тут вопросов к докладчику нет, этот момент действительно заслуживает отдельной упоминания.